# update java arraylist changes dynamically in html

Tags: java, html, jsp, openfire, smack

I have a array list in java which contains notification messages which will be displayed in a html page.

Is there way that when the array list gets updated(i will update this array list from the listeners in smack chat library) the list in html also gets updated simultaneously without refreshing the page.

I am not interested in hitting the controller using any scheduler that will update the list every x minutes.I need the  list to be updated simultaneously.

I have heard that we can use web sockets on this.I have no idea on this.Is that the way to go.If so kindly provide the tutorial for the same.

Comment: use (`javascript` / `AJAX`) to update in real time...

Comment: that means every x minutes i hit a controller through ajax get the updated list and modify it without refresh right

Comment: *I am not interested in hitting the controller*. How else your html  page on client would know that some list on server has changed.?

Comment: But i am not interested hitting the controller that many times if arraylist is not getting updated for long time

Comment: @ares that is what i thought tooo.But i heard something like web sockets would update my html dynamically i am not sure though

Comment: I don't know about web sockets but you can look into `Server Push`. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html) is a tutorial for that.

Comment: *that means every x minutes i hit a controller through ajax* WTF??? **absolutelly not**, you just hit the ajax request when list is updated in listeners.... Please check an AJAX and a client-server sides tutorial start there and don't expect magic updates your views....

Answer (score 0):

There are many technology to make chatting application over web browser.

1. **HTTP server push** - nothing but HTTP streaming, which uses   WebSocket API and browser should support HTML5, server can push the message to the client.
2. **Pushlet** - it takes the advantages of the  persistent HTTP connections. and communicate using that connection.
3. **Long polling** - pull the data using ajax and jquery or any ajax based technique.
4. **Flash XMLSocket** - when your browser does not support HTML5 that time this can be used.

I worked with same kind of application where , we developed all the technique depending upon the user browser support, we invoke the appropriate technique.

you can get more info about WebSocket [here](https://pusher.com/websockets)

Comment: Sounds Good Thanks i will have a look at it